# How to run more than 6 machines in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am using Vagrant in [multi-machine](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/) configuration with:

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "..."
```

but I am not able to provision more than 6 machines, because:

```
There is no available slots on the VirtualBox VM for the configured
high-level network interfaces. "private_network" and "public_network"
network configurations consume a single network adapter slot on the
VirtualBox VM. VirtualBox limits the number of slots to 8, and it
appears that every slot is in use. Please lower the number of used
network adapters.
```

Tried both private_network and public_network, same results. On last provisioned machine, I see a lot of eth* interfaces, not sure if it is related. I **do not** need that machines can communicate between themselves, so maybe there is a config to achieve this?

Vagrant version is 1.4.3, VirtualBox is 4.3.34, host is Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: Which versions of VirtualBox and Vagrant? And what is the host OS?

Comment: Vagrant version is 1.4.3, VirtualBox is 4.3.34, host is Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: The most recent version of Vagrant is 1.8.1 and VirtualBox 5 has been available for a while. I recommend upgrading both and then seeing if this problem persists. BTW: I also use Mint. Good choice!

Comment: I guess you have an error in your Vagrantfile. Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

can you open Virtual Box and edit the configuration of your VM.

Go to the system setting and select ICH9 chipset in the motherboard tab.

from [virtual box documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html)

> Using the ICH9 chipset it is also possible to configure up to 36
>   network cards (up to 8 network adapters with PIIX3). Note that the
>   ICH9 support is experimental and not recommended for guest operating
>   systems which do not require it

so it should pass the limitation of the 8 network adapters but do not guarantee everything would work as it is still experimental

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue here. The OP want's to start more than 6 vms and not more than 8 interfaces per machine. I guess the OP has an error in the Vagrantfile.

Comment: Right, I had an error in config file after all:

  `config.vm.define "p0" do |p0|

    p0.vm.hostname = "p0"

    p0.vm.box = "p0"

    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.10"

  end`

Notice the "config" which is copy-paste left-over from going from single to multi machine. Sorry for wasting everybody's time